# Angular 7 nested observables

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscription, angular2-observables

I have two collections: persons and pets. Every pet has personId. My target is to get all persons and foreach of them to add his/her pets in single json. What I did so far is:

```
this.personService.getPersions().subscribe(persons => {
  const personsWithPets = persons.flatMap(person => this.petService.getPetsByPersonId(person._id)
    .subscribe(petsData => {
      person.pets = petsData;
      return person;
    }, (err) => {
     console.log(err);
    }));
  this.persons = personsWithPets; // This is fired before previous subscribe
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

What I do wrong? Why `this.persons = personsWithPets;` is fired before subscription finish?

Comment: because your `getPetsByPersonId` is probably asynchronus, so the code inside your call to `getPetsByPersonId().subscribe` will likely not return a value until after `this.persons = personsWithPets`.  The `subscribe` is called, just the code inside won't run until the service returns a value.  It really has nothing to do with nested observables

Comment: Any suggestions to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** added comments

Another one: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tumkce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
this.service.getPersons().pipe(switchMap((per:any[])=>{
       //create an array of observables
       const obs=per.map(per=>this.service.getPet(per.id));
       //call all of them in forkjoin
       return forkJoin(obs).pipe(map(pets=>
         //pets is an array, in pets[0] is the response of getPet(1), 
         //in pets[1] is the response of getPet(2)
         pets.map((pet,i)=>{
           return {
             ...per[i], //all the properties of the person
             pets:pet   //+ in pets an array with the pets of the person
             }
         })
       ))
     })).subscribe(res=>this.res=res)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made an example for you

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap, toArray, mergeMap } = rxjs.operators;

function getPeople() {
  return of([{ id: 1, name: 'Amanda' }, { id: 2, name: 'Nancy' }]);
}

function getPetsByPersonId(id) {
  switch(id) {
    case 1:
      return of(['Doggie']);
    case 2:
      return of(['Kitten']);
  }
}

const getPets = (person) => {
  return getPetsByPersonId(person.id).pipe(
    map(pets => ({ ...person, pets }))
  )
}

getPeople().pipe(
  switchMap(people => people),
  mergeMap(getPets),
  toArray()
)
  .subscribe(peopleWithPets => console.log(peopleWithPets));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: pipe did not exist on type Subscription

Comment: Which pipe? getPetsByPersonId or getPeople? Could you please post those functions code?

Comment: now I got TypeError: this.getPetsByPersonId is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Using subscribe inside subscribe is considered as a bad practice and may lead to problems as you described. I would suggest to use mergeMap combined with forkJoin operator:

```js
this.personService.getPersions().pipe(mergeMap(persons => {
   const requests = persons.map(person => this.petService.getPetsByPersonId(person._id));
   return forkJoin(of(persons), ...requests);
}),
map(values => {
  const persons = values[0];
  const pets = values.slice(1);
  // here you need to assign correct pet to correct person

})
).subscribe(personsWithPets => {
  console.log(personsWithPets);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This map(values => { returns me proper array of pets, but how to combine person and values[nth]?

Answer (score 0):

Observables are asynchronous by nature. The subscribe call will be run in another thread while the rest of the instructions in the method will continue to run in the main thread. What you need to do is wait until the asynchronous action completes before running the next one. You can do this by putting the isntructions inside of the subscription, or better yet use the onCompleted parameter which comes after the (err) param, like so

```
this.personService.getPersons().subscribe(persons => {
  const personsWithPets = persons.flatMap(person => 
        this.petService.getPetsByPersonId(person._id)
            .subscribe(petsData => {
                 person.pets = petsData;
                 return person;
             }, 
             (err) => {
                 console.log(err);
             },
             () => {
                 this.persons = personsWithPets;
             }))
        });
```